# Algebra problem related to calculus and binomial formula

Tags: calculus, binomial-theorem, maxima-minima

Consider the following quantity:
$$
(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-q)^{n-2}+(n-2)q(1-q)^{n-3}-(n-2)p(1-p)^{n-3}
$$
where $n\ge4$ is an integer, and $q-p\triangleq c$ is supposed to be fixed and in the interval $(0,1)$, i.e., the quantity can also be written as:
$$
(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-p-c)^{n-2}+(n-2)(p+c)(1-p-c)^{n-3}-(n-2)p(1-p)^{n-3}
$$

How can I show that this quantity is positive for $p\in (1/n-c/2,2/n-c/2)$?

Simulation shows that this quantity is decreasing in the given interval, so I tried taking derivative w.r.t. $p$, trying to show it's negative and solve the problem by plugging in $p=2/n-c/2$, but it gives a quantity similar to the quantity of interest, so either it doesn't really help, or I'm missing something here.

I have also tried using binomial formula to break up the parentheses, but couldn't get anything meaningful also.

Any suggestion and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the equals sign with the triangle over it mean?

Comment: @MatthewConroy, Oh I was trying to say 'defined as'.

Comment: Is this a probability calculation? Could you give more context for this problem, to make solving it more interesting for others (me, anyway)? Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewConroy, exactly! How did you tell? Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311012/sum-of-binomial-random-variable-cdf/2311110#2311110 for detail. Obviously this question comes from the linked one when only looking at one continuous interval

Comment: The use of $p$ and $q$, and then $1-p$ and $1-q$ is a big tip-off.

Comment: @MatthewConroy, What do you mean? I didn't quite get that...

Comment: The choice of those letters for your variables: $p$ and $q$ are often used for probability, and $1-p$ is meaningful if $p$ is a probability, too, so these are clues to a reader that you might be working with probabilities. Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy Oh, you're right! That's some fine observation. Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like an interesting problem to me.  Perhaps others will find interest in it.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy, Thanks anyways :-)